# Seeing Reason for Reputation Points

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeek! What happened to my envelope?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope)

Time was, when I saw my reputation has gone up a little, I could click the little envelope in the small header bar and anything that affected my reputation that I hadn't already seen appeared. The envelope didn't make that much sense but it seemed to work great.

Now the envelope is gone and I just got some reputation points and can't seem to find out where they came from.

Am I missing the new way to find this information, or was it decided I didn't want to know it?

Comment: It's still available on http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent Yet there's no link anymore.

Comment: @BalusC: Interesting. That's a long thread without much resolution. It seems to suggested the functionality is gone.

Comment: @BalusC: Yep, that's the link. So, what, we need to type the link by hand now? I guess that's progress for you.

Comment: I've it in my FF bookmark bar now. Not for long, I hope.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the word "Reputation."  It's a link that will take you to your rep graph, which will show you where you got the rep.

You can also still view the old page here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent

(Thanks to Daniel and BalusC for pointing that out.)

But,

> We can't guarantee these links will continue to work, these pages were very inefficient,   especially for very active users. We will continue to improve the destination pages that the popup links to though. – Nick Craver♦

Comment: @John: No, that link specifically does not show the information I described. (Unless it's hidden somewhere.)

Comment: @Jon: Scroll down. :) It's under the graph.

Comment: @John: Ah, I see it. Hmmm... It's there, but what previous took one click now takes two clicks and a scroll. :-(

Comment: @John the rep graph is broken in a lot of instances, unfortunately, the `/recent` page is still the best place to see the correct information

Comment: @Jon: Sad, but true.

Comment: @Daniel: True.  I was unaware that still existed when I posted this.